How do permit inspectors sign off permit if plumbing holes have been covered?
I had a severe plumbing leak in my foundation, so the whole house was re-plumbed to go through the attic and down.
This created over a dozen large holes throughout my house. The contractors for repair of the walls and kitchen are now almost complete with all the repairs.
I just thought about the fact that we did not see an inspector come out after all the plumbing was complete (before the walls were repaired). How will the inspector sign off the permit in this case?

Typically the contractor would bring in the inspection before closing up the repair. I had a sewer line replaced under the lawn and the inspector came before the contractor buried the pipes. In your case, either the inspection happened and you missed it or the contractor didn't actually file for permits so no inspection is done.

Do you have a permit  and is it hung in a conspicuous area?  An inspector will "sign off" on this permit.  This is normal for my area, (Fl.) but other areas of the country are different. We cannot answer your question without knowing what the process is in your area.

Several scenarios come to mind.

It is possible that your contractor has already organised the inspector to have a look.
The inspector may accept photos of the work done.
Ask the contractor how he is going to get it certified.
It does not require a certificate, especially if you are not moving wet areas.
Its a stuff up - call the inspector and plead ignorance.


Although not typical, it could also be that the plumbing contractor has such a good reputation with the inspector that the inspector knows from experience the plumbing contractor did everything to code and takes their word for it.

@Milwrdfan   Had an electrician doing some work that required the main breaker to be off.  After the work was finished, found the main to be broken.  He just snipped the lock on the meter, replaced the main, and told power company what happen.  Power company came out a couple months later to replaced the lock, no questions.  Depends on how well the person is known.
